# Dynamic memory allocation with int array

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free, realloc

I have an assignment in which I have to accept an input from the user. I can't use a linked list, only an array, so my plan is:

1. Alloc some memory.
2. If we need to realloc, meaning that I reached the number of cells allocated:

   1. Try to realloc. If successful, great.
   2. If we couldn't realloc, print input, free memory and realloc then.

I can't really decide about the command that tells me how did I reach the end of memory allocated and that's why I need your help. I wrote:

```
if (i==(MAX_CHARS_INPUT-1))
```

But I am not sure about it.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CHARS_INPUT 200
#define D_SIZE 2

void printWithMalloc(){
    int charSize=1; 
    int *ptr=malloc(MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(charSize));

    int i=0, j=0, c;
    printf("please enter a string\n");

    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')
    {
        ptr[i++]=c;
        if (i==(MAX_CHARS_INPUT-1)) /*if we need to realloc*/
        {
            int *temp=realloc(ptr,D_SIZE*MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(charSize));
            if (temp==NULL) /*realloc failed*/
            {
                printf("you wrote:\n");
                while(j<=i)
                    putchar(ptr[j++]);

                free(ptr);
                ptr=(int*)malloc(MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(charSize));
            }
            else
                ptr=temp;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    printWithMalloc();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `sizeof(charSize)` will give you the size of an int since harSize is an int. Instead, just do `sizeof(char)`

Comment: Even better, omit it completely, as `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1.

Comment: you may want to reconsider doing a realloc with an extra 2 bytes since it's not very effective, if your environment is not an embedded one (where every byte counts) simply add a block of say 100 bytes if space is not enough, it would reduce the number of reallocs. Have a variable the keep tracks of the buffer size, increase this when you realloc.

Comment: `ptr` is a buffer of `int`s, not `char`s. `sizeof(charSize)` may seem confused but it is (perhaps unintentionally) correct. Use `sizeof *ptr` instead, as that will always work, especially if you ever change the type of `ptr`.

Comment: @Kninnug, charSize is intetentional to initilize each cell to be 1 bit even though it's int. Maybe I should change the name of the variable? Thank you all for answering.

Comment: (I assume you mean 1 *byte*) What you do does not initialize each cell to be 1 byte. As your pointer is an `int`-pointer each 'cell' is the size of an `int`, `malloc`ing with a different size does not change that and in fact causes huge problems since you'll run past the allocated buffer much faster (as `sizeof(int)` is almost always more than `sizeof(char)`). If you want your cells to be one byte, make it a `char`-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed with your condition:

```
if (i==(MAX_CHARS_INPUT-1))
```

This works, but only for the first time you reach this limit. When you `realloc` your buffer gets bigger, but you don't check if you run out of *that* space. So imagine I input 500 characters. When the 199th character is read the buffer is reallocated to become 400 characters big. However, `i` is *only* checked at the 199th character, so when the 400th one is reached it will run out of the buffer.

The second problem is that when you reallocate the buffer it will only grow to 400 characters (`D_SIZE * MAX_CHARS_INPUT`) and no bigger.

The third problem is when you re-`malloc` (i.e. when `realloc` failed) you don't reset `i` so it will write past the end of the buffer immediately.

As suggested in a now deleted answer. Keep track of your buffer-size:

```
size_t buffSize = MAX_CHARS_INPUT;
```

when you reallocate, update `buffSize` first, then use that as the argument to `realloc`:

```
buffSize *= D_SIZE; // double the buffer-size
temp = realloc(ptr, buffSize * sizeof(*temp)); // using sizeof *temp is less confusing and less error-prone
```

of course: also update your condition:

```
if(i == buffSize - 1)
```

and when you re-`malloc` reset `i` and `buffSize`:

```
buffSize = MAX_CHARS_INPUT;
ptr = malloc(buffSize*sizeof(*ptr));
i = 0;
```

Though re-`malloc`ing is not very wise, since if an allocation fails there are usually bigger problems (unless memory is very restricted). And (especially since you don't check the result of that `malloc`) possibly problematic since that `malloc` may fail as well. Exiting a program after an alloc-fail is not unusual.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things getting wrong in your code, the new code is:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define MAX_CHARS_INPUT 200
  #define D_SIZE 2

  void printWithMalloc(){
      //int charSize=1; you don't need this.
      //int *ptr=malloc(MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(charSize));
      char *ptr=malloc(MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(char));//sizeof(char) will give you the block size, MAX_CHARS_INPUT: gives you the number of blocks to be allocated and pointer type is char, since you want to save char(s), right?

      int i=0, j=0, c;
      printf("please enter a string\n");

      //while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')
       while ((c=getchar())!='\r') //'\r' is for enter key... since the user input is coming from console not form a file, right?
      {
          ptr[i++]=c;
          if (i==(MAX_CHARS_INPUT-1)) /*if we need to realloc*/
          if (i==MAX_CHARS_INPUT) // i is already incremented in i++
          {
              //int *temp=realloc(ptr,D_SIZE*MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(charSize));
              char *temp=realloc(ptr,D_SIZE*MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(char));
              if (temp==NULL) /*realloc failed*/
              {
                  printf("you wrote:\n");
                  while(j<=i)
                      putchar(ptr[j++]);

                  free(ptr);
                  ptr=(char*)malloc(MAX_CHARS_INPUT*sizeof(char));
              }
              else
                  ptr=temp;
          }
      }
  }

  int main(){
      printWithMalloc();
      return 0;
  }
```